# How to write a character/symbol similar to \k{A} for the character L?

Tags: symbols, accents, characters

We have a character \k{A} which seems like merging of two letters like 'A' and 'c'.
I need a character similar to merge of 'L' and 'c'.

But don't want to use the already defined characters like \L or \c{L}. 
So what should be done?

Comment: Why don't you use `\k{L}`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a “c”, but an *ogonek* (in Polish it means “little tail”).

When you load the T1 encoding for fonts, it's already available in two forms: either at the far right of the character or centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\k{L} \k{A} \k{E}

\textogonekcentered{L}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you add `\usepackage{lmodern}`, it's not as good, because the ogonek gets almost centered anyway, but on the other hand the shape is better. This becomes unacceptable for the lowercase “l”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\k{L} \k{l}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can get the best of both worlds:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{lmodern}{%
  \UndeclareTextCommand{\k}{T1}%
  \DeclareTextCommand{\k}{T1}[1]%
   {\hmode@bgroup\ooalign{\null#1\crcr\hidewidth\char12\kern-.2ex}\egroup}%
  \DeclareTextComposite{\k}{T1}{A}{129}%
  \DeclareTextComposite{\k}{T1}{E}{134}%
  \DeclareTextComposite{\k}{T1}{a}{161}%
  \DeclareTextComposite{\k}{T1}{e}{166}%
  \DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\k}{T1}{o}{\textogonekcentered{o}}%
  \DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\k}{T1}{O}{\textogonekcentered{O}}%
}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\k{E}

\k{L} \k{l}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @psmears Uh, yes, I'll fix it

Answer (score 5):

Two varieties shown, along with the `\k{A}` and `\k{L}` for comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\k{A} 
\k{L}
\stackengine{0pt}{L}{\tiny c}{U}{r}{F}{F}{S}
\stackengine{-.3pt}{L}{\tiny c\kern.3pt}{U}{r}{F}{F}{S}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\lowc[1]{%
  \sbox0{\tiny c}
  #1\kern-\wd0\raisebox{-\ht0}{\usebox0}
}
\begin{document}
\lowc{L} and \lowc{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for fun you can add an optional parameter for the lower letter by changing the definition to

```
\newcommand\lowc[2][c]{%
  \sbox0{\tiny #1}
  #2\kern-\wd0\raisebox{-\ht0}{\usebox0}
}
```

and then e.g.

```
\lowc[s]{L} and \lowc[$\xi$]{L}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you by chance looking for the CENTER LINE SYMBOL ℄ (Unicode U+2104)? I couldn't locate a ready-made one, therefore try this macro (requires package `relsize` for the command `\smaller`)

```
\newcommand*\centerlinesym{\raisebox{.44ex}{\smaller{c}}\kern -0.37em{L}}
```

Here is a little test of it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
H{\raisebox{ .44ex}{\smaller{c}}}\kern -0.37em{L}H
\end{document}
```

[image]